# Get actual logged in Windows user name

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, security, winapi

I have looked all over the internet for this and I can't find an answer that actually works. Is there a way besides Environment.UserName, GetCurrentProcess().UserName, WMI, etc. to get the logged in windows user, not the process user?

Comment: There can be multiple users logged into the system with active sessions (or none).

Comment: I think you need to explain what your trying to do, and what problem you're running into. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Hmm. Well the reason I want to do this is for a weird reason. I basically want to dynamically format a route using the username of the devs in my office who are all working on the same website so I don't need to change the web.config for every dev since we share one file in the repo. Our local address for our website is {username}.site.com. That way we can view our server's site in meetings remotely and have it function like our production site for other testing.

Answer (score 0):

Web pages: `Page.User.Identity.Name`

Razor Views: `User.Identity.Name`

Answer (score 0):

```
User.Identity.GetUserName()
```

This will get the username of the user in a Razor view.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Will get the username of the logged in user in asp.net including any Domain.